# How can I add connectionstring inside Program.cs in .net 7 at a Winform project?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-7.0

I use .net 7 in my Winform project and there is no appconfig, so I want to write connectionstring inside Program.cs But I don't know how do that can you help me please.

Comment: You can replace `app.config` with `appsettings.json`. See the [Basic example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration#basic-example) documentation (without Hosting or Dependency Injection)

Comment: thank you.I konw this way. but is there  a way   without  using app.config. I only want to use program.cs

Comment: Well, then just add a public Field, e.g., `public static string MyConnectionString = string.Empty;` and assign a value in `main`. If you want to make it `readonly`, then you have to add a static Constructor, e.g., `public static readonly string MyConnectionString = string.Empty;  static Program() => MyConnectionString = "Some string";`